# Starting application from shell does not use HiDPI configuration

Tags: anaconda, archlinux, kde-plasma, hidpi

I have a Dell XPS 15 with a 4k monitor. I am using ArchLinux and KDE.

When I start an application from the menu, the application is properly scaled.
When I start it from the shell, for example "kate filename", the configuration HiDPI is not taken into consideration and the application is unusable (the window is too big).

It is not a problem when the application can be started from the menu but when there is no such shortcut like for 'anaconda-navigator', the application cannot be used.

Does someone know how to have the shell takes the HiDPI setup when starting an application ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I badly configured my shell. KDE scaling factors do not mix well with some environment variables regarding scaling.
I removed all env var related to scaling from zsh and it worked as expected.